# MVC 3 Razor - Use script references in Layout page from Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I used some jquery in my partial view and realised that I need to have the script reference put in the partial view Again in order for the jquery to works.

I wonder is there any method which I can "call" all the script references in the Layout page so I dont need to duplicate it in the Partial View??

I tried to search for related information and tried to use @section to store the script references, but it seems cant work.

Hope can get some guide here... Appreciate it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put all your script references in a Partial View of its own, and then call `@Html.Partial("ScriptReferences")` from both the Layout page and the other Partial View that needs the script references.

Answer (score 3):

I normally include/reference all the scripts in my layout view. Although some are not needed on all pages.

The partial views, do not have to worry about a script not available. And it also saves time during development.

The overhead of having all scripts available is minimal. Specially if you merge all .js files in one big minimized script ([Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/) can do that for you). Modern browsers will know it's the same script and not download and parse them over and over.

Comment: Sorry but you mean by ""The partial views, do not have to worry about a script not available.""?? All the script references in my Layout page is not available in Partial View.. they are only available in normal View

Comment: Your partial view gets rendered as HTML the same as your view and so when it comes to run time your partial views will have access to scripts that are referenced on the `_Layout.cshtml` page the same as any other view

Comment: But i cant get my script working in the partial view if i do not duplicate the script references in the partial view, any idea what is the reason??
Really thanks...

Comment: "xxx" is not defined;
"xxx" is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Script references in Layout page are automatically shared with partial views. You might encounter issues if the Home page (which loads layout) URL and the partial view URLs are not relative ... Use relative URLs to load the partial views and the sharing of script file references and global namespaces would work ...

Answer (score 0):

I found another option that turned out to make my life a lot better:
http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/asp-dot-net-mvc3-razor-script-loading-tips